# The import com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager cannot be resolved

Tags: google-glass

Following a Livecard tutorial, I realized that eclipse keeps throwing the following error: "import com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager cannot be resolved". The solution I found online was to set the project to compile with the Glass GDK by changing the build target to Glass Development Kit Sneak Peak version 15.

I dont have a Glass Development kit sneak peek under Android 4.0.3. I downloaded the ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. However, I have a Glass Development kit preview under the android 4.2.2, version 19.

Could that be the problem as to why timelineManager is not being identified or imported?

I can't move forward until I figure this out.. =(

Here is a screenshot of the error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14109184/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-31%20at%209.42.38%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TimelineManager was removed with XE16 with no immediate replacement. If you're planning on creating a GDK based app going forward - don't try to use the old GDK.

If you really need to insert a static card, you may wish to evaluate the Mirror API to see if it meets your needs.